# Why do my centroids lies on the graph axis in MATLAB using k-means clustering?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do a very simple k-means clustering in MATLAB and have a dataset of 732 x 1. I used the code below to generate the graph however, the position of centroids keeps landing on the y-axis which doesn't make any sense.  If I were to just plot `C` without using the `hold` function the centroids appears to be in positions other than the axis. I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Here's the code that I wrote to reproduce my problem:

```
figure;
[idx,C,sumd,D] = kmeans(EnginePower,6,'start','uniform','Distance','cityblock','Replicates',10,'display','iter');

plot(C(:,1),'kx','MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',3)
hold on
plot(Time(:,2),EnginePower,'.');
hold off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your data is 1D, it doesn't make any sense to plot your centroids on a **2D grid**.  What you should probably do is plot all of your data on the `x`-axis (i.e. keeping the `y` component constant).  Use something like `x = 0` to plot your centroids and your data.  As such, do something like this:

```
plot(C,0,'kx','MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',3)    
hold on    
plot(EnginePower,0,'.');   
grid;
hold off
```

Note that doing `C(:,1)` is superfluous as `C` is already a 1D array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new to this algorithm and by 1D data do you mean my EnginePower(the value of this engine power is measure over 732 interval) or centroids ? Anyway, i tried your way and all my points and centroids end up in a straight line on the y axis.

Comment: I change engine data into 732x2 data with the changes in the following code plot(EnginePower(:,2),EnginePower(:,1),'.',C(:,2),C(:,1),'kx','MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',3); turns out my graph appears to be alright. Thanks for you help in pointing out the 1D

Comment: @TKAlive - No problem.  I wouldn't mind if you accepted my answer as I pointed you in the right direction.  Good luck!